# Is it possible to change the Provider within a connection string via a .dtsConfig file?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a Connection string for a deployed SSIS package that looks like:

```
Data Source=DBServerName;Initial Catalog=DbName;Provider=SQLNCLI11;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;
```

There is an existing .dtsConfig file that already has entries that alter the Server Name and database name:

```
    <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[MyConnection].Properties[InitialCatalog]" ValueType="String">
    <ConfiguredValue>DbName</ConfiguredValue>
  </Configuration>

  <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[MyConnection].Properties[ServerName]" ValueType="String">
    <ConfiguredValue>DBServerName</ConfiguredValue>
  </Configuration>
```

I would like to add an additional entry to this to try and alter the Provider name. I have tried something like this:

```
  <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[MyConnection].Properties[Provider]" ValueType="String">
    <ConfiguredValue>MSOLEDBSQL</ConfiguredValue>
  </Configuration>
```

However this is not being picked up. I notice that for the other two the names of the properties do not match up exactly with the names that are in the connection string. I was wondering does Provider go by some other name that needs to be used instead?
Is it even possible to alter the Provider name like this?

Comment: As far as I can see, the provider cannot be set by an expression. That you want to change the provider dynamically feels like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info), in truth.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you can't do it with properties piecemealed as you're showing. You can either specify everything in the ConnectionString or not change the provider.

As an example, I put everything under the tree into a config file

[image]

This is what I see

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DTSConfiguration>
    <DTSConfigurationHeading>
        <DTSConfigurationFileInfo GeneratedBy="HOME\bfellows" GeneratedFromPackageName="SO_67389233" GeneratedFromPackageID="{DE300BCB-F7C1-4D7F-9BD3-3E109E806CFA}" GeneratedDate="1/9/2024 9:09:23 AM"/>
    </DTSConfigurationHeading>
    <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[.\dev2017].Properties[ConnectionString]" ValueType="String">
        <ConfiguredValue>Data Source=.\dev2017;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;</ConfiguredValue>
    </Configuration>
    <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[.\dev2017].Properties[Description]" ValueType="String">
        <ConfiguredValue/>
    </Configuration>
    <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[.\dev2017].Properties[InitialCatalog]" ValueType="String">
        <ConfiguredValue/>
    </Configuration>
    <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[.\dev2017].Properties[Name]" ValueType="String">
        <ConfiguredValue>.\dev2017</ConfiguredValue>
    </Configuration>
    <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[.\dev2017].Properties[Password]" ValueType="String">
        <ConfiguredValue/>
    </Configuration>
    <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[.\dev2017].Properties[ProtectionLevel]" ValueType="Int32">
        <ConfiguredValue>1</ConfiguredValue>
    </Configuration>
    <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[.\dev2017].Properties[RetainSameConnection]" ValueType="Boolean">
        <ConfiguredValue>0</ConfiguredValue>
    </Configuration>
    <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[.\dev2017].Properties[Scope]" ValueType="Int32">
        <ConfiguredValue>0</ConfiguredValue>
    </Configuration>
    <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[.\dev2017].Properties[ServerName]" ValueType="String">
        <ConfiguredValue>.\dev2017</ConfiguredValue>
    </Configuration>
    <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[.\dev2017].Properties[UserName]" ValueType="String">
        <ConfiguredValue/>
    </Configuration>
</DTSConfiguration>
```

As [Thom A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77786708/is-it-possible-to-change-the-provider-within-a-connection-string-via-a-dtsconfi#comment137130810_77786708) comments, the property itself does not have an individual setting listed. *But*, if you instead just use the `ConnectionString` property, then look at what you have.

> Data Source=.\dev2017;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;

The connection string property *does* include the Provider property.

If I strip that config file down to just ConnectionString and replace the Provider=SQLNCLI11.1 with Provider=SQLOLEDB.1

```
    <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[.\dev2017].Properties[ConnectionString]" ValueType="String">
        <ConfiguredValue>Data Source=.\dev2017;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;</ConfiguredValue>
    </Configuration>
```

Open/close the package and now my connection manager is showing the updated Provider.